# Как можно сделать из navbar sidebar для мобильного?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, scss, sidebar

Каким образом можно сделать из горизонтального navbar sidebar, находящийся слева для мобильных устройств?
Это код для веб версии.

HTML

```
<div class="container-header">
  <img class="logo" src="/assets/img/icons/brox_sm.svg">
  <div class="tags">
    <ul class="auth-tags">
      <li>Нужна помощь?</li>
      <li>Зарегистрироваться</li>
      <li><button class="login">Войти</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.container-header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #1F1F1F;

  .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 127px;
  }

  .tags {
    text-align: center;

    .header-tags li, .auth-tags li {
      display: table-cell;
      padding-right: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
    }

    .auth-tags {
      margin-top: 20px;
      float: right;
      font-family: PT Sans;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 150%;
      color: #FFFFFF;

      li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2)  {
        padding-left: 70px;
      }

      .login {
        width: 138px;
        border: 1px solid #F08417;
        background-color: #1F1F1F;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Нужно сделать как на скрине:

[image: Sidebar for mobile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот держите самый простой пример:

```js
$('.burger, .menu_nav>a').click(function() {
  $('.burger').toggleClass('open');
  $('.menu_nav').toggleClass('menu_nav_active');
});
```

```css
/*Меню*/

.menu_nav {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  border-right: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu_nav_active {
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 113px solid #137995;
}

.menu_nav>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.menu_nav>a:hover {
  background: #1d606f;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .menu_nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .menu_nav>a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
}


/*Иконка*/

.burger {
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 33px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #137995;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.burger-brick {
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.open .burger-brick:first-child {
  margin-top: 14px;
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

.open .burger-brick:last-child {
  margin-top: -14px;
  transform: rotate(-405deg);
}

.open .middle {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="burger">
  <div class="burger-brick"></div>
  <div class="burger-brick middle"></div>
  <div class="burger-brick"></div>
</div>
<nav class="menu_nav">
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Каталог скинали</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Этапы работ</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu_link">Примеры работ</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: а каким образом можно переписать эту функцию на typescript?